# Disabling multiple Middle-clicks in quick-succession with AutoHotkey

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I open new links in Chrome with middle clicks. But lately I've been noticed the links opening twice or more tabs when I do a middle click. This might be me inadvertently clicking twice when I intend to middle click once.

How do I make it so once I click middle click, Windows ignores any other middle click in the next 500ms (with AutoHotkey)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
MButton::
    If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 500)
        Send {MButton}
return
```

Where `500` is the number of milliseconds to wait.

Comment: Yours works great :) I found a similar but a line longer solution for it from ahk forums old posts. this is what i used.

`code  Fix the middle-click-opening-multiple-tabs-with-one-mid-click-issue
MButton::
 if (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 150) ;hyperclick disallow it
  return
 Send {MButton}
return`